# Prove: $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not divisible by $2^n-1$ if $n>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove: $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not divisible by $2^n-1$ if $n>1$

Using induction:

For $n=2\Rightarrow 2$ is not divisible by $3$

For $n=k\Rightarrow k$ is not divisible by $2^k-1$

For $n=k+1\Rightarrow k+1$ is not divisible by $2^{k+1}-1$

How to prove this by induction?

Comment: Try proving that $2^n-1 > n$ if $n>1$

Comment: Try using the contraposition: $k+1$ is  divisible by $2^{k+1}−1  \Rightarrow  k$ is  divisible by $2^k−1$